# Copy Original Emoticon Character to UIPasteBoard Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, emoji, uipasteboard

When I copy the original character such as: ♥ and then when I paste it looks like [image: this]

How can I keep the original character when I paste?

Comment: It just sounds like you're using a different font in the copied-from and pasted-to locations.  If you use the same font, the character will look the same.

Comment: @CarlNorum How can I keep the same font? I'm pasting it into spotlight and other apps.

Comment: It appears Apple is mapping that to the emoji images http://unicode.org/~scherer/emoji4unicode/snapshot/utc.html

Comment: @s0ulp1xel, you can't.  The destination app is going to decide what to do with whatever you put on the pasteboard.  It's not your choice.  If you are handling the paste in *your* app, you can do whatever you want, of course.